# Estimating survival curve with changepoint from Poisson regression

Tags: survival, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, piecewise-pdf

Suppose I fit data according to the following piecewise exponential model. So that the intensity is 1/50 for event times in the first 50 days and then 1/200 subsequently.

```
library(survival)
set.seed(123)
x <- rexp(100, 1/50)
x[x > 50] <- 50 + rexp(sum(x > 50), 1/200)

plot(survfit(Surv(x)  ~1), conf.int = F)
```

[image]

I find I can estimate the survival curve for modeling the incorrect Exponential process

In a misspecified (non-piecewise) exponential model, I can replicate the results of a survival regression using Poisson regression to estimate a process with constant intensity. (In this example, the value is approx 1/115 which can be verified using the law of total expectation).

```
i <- rep(1, 100)
f <- glm(i ~offset(log(x)), family=poisson)
nd <- data.frame('x'=sort(x))
lines(nd$x, exp(-predict(f, newdata = nd, type='response')), col='red')
```

[image]

However, I then try to fit a breakpoint for the intensity at the $x=50$ mark and the process fails catastrophically.

```
g <- glm(i ~ I(x>50) + offset(log(x)), family=poisson)
lines(nd$x, exp(-predict(g, newdata = nd, type='response')), col='blue')
```

[image]

In case 1 with constant process, I expected the prediction from a Poisson GLM corresponds to $\lambda t$ with $\lambda = \exp(\beta_0)$ which is both the expected number of events at time $t$ and is also the cumulative hazard. In case 2, the model coefficients are estimated to be -3.0 and -2.4 or $\lambda = 1/20$ for $t<50$ and $\lambda = 1/220$ for $t>50$ which is close to the model specification. But I cannot connect the predictions to the cumulative incidence or rather the cumulative hazard of the piecewise survival function.

** How can I estimate the piecewise survival curve from model output g?**